# elasticsearch termvectors result page size

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET /myindex/voc/100/_termvectors?pretty=true
{
    "fields":["fields.bodyText"],
    "term_statistics" : true,
    "filter" : {
      "min_doc_freq" : 50,
      "max_doc_freq" : 60
    }
}
```

This API returns only part of the results.
Is there something like

```
"from" : 0, "size" : 10,
```

as in the _search API pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, something like `from` which represents from which index you got to start the search, and the `size` represents the number of hits you wanted to return.

So if you have something like this:

```
"from" : 0, "size" : 10,
```

It'll return your first ten results from the result set. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) could be helpful.